# How to properly do null checks using Kotlin extension functions on an Android Activity

Tags: java, android, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions, kotlin-null-safety

I'm new to Kotlin and trying to convert one of the many Android Util methods we have in our existing codebase into a Kotlin extension function.

This is the Kotlin code:

```
fun Activity?.isAlive(): Boolean {
    return !(this?.isFinishing ?: false)
}
```

Which is meant to be the equivalent of this Java method:

```
public static boolean isAlive(Activity activity) {
    return activity != null && !activity.isFinishing();
}
```

However, I'm still getting `NPEs` in the Kotlin code whenever an `Activity` is `null`. Any thoughts on where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suppose you get NPE not in the `isAlive()` function but somewhere after, when the `Activity` is referenced. This is likely caused by the fact that `.isAlive()` returns `true` on `null` receiver.

That's because if the receiver is `null`, `this?.isFinishing ?: false` chooses the right branch `false`, thus `!(this?.isFinishing ?: false)` is `true`.

Try changing your function in either way so that it returns `false` on `null` receiver, for example:

```
fun Activity?.isAlive(): Boolean = !(this?.isFinishing ?: true)
```

Comment: im using this@ClassName?.isAlive()?.let {  some alerdialog } in onPostExecute
still got exception BadTokenException: Unable to add window

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest writing

```
fun Activity?.isAlive(): Boolean = this != null && !this.isFinishing
```

I find the separate null check and condition easier to read than the combined versions.

Answer (score 0):

While the accepted answer works fine I'd suggest using an equality check instead, since it results in far more readable code:

```
fun Activity?.isAlive(): Boolean = this?.isFinishing == false
```